# activate javascript block of code

Tags: javascript, html, button, block

I have a Javascript block of code but I don't know how to activate it.
I would like it to be activated with a HTML button but I don't know if it's possible. I'm just beginning in coding =P

Here's the code:

```
var randomFlavour = Math.random() * 10;

if (randomFlavour < 1) {
    var randomFlavour = "chocolate";
} else if (randomFlavour < 2) {
    var randomFlavour = "vanilla";
} else if (randomFlavour < 3) {
    var randomFlavour = "pistachio";
} else if (randomFlavour < 4) {
    var randomFlavour = "strawberry";
} else if (randomFlavour < 5) {
    var randomFlavour = "cotton candy";
} else if (randomFlavour < 6) {
    var randomFlavour = "cookie dough";
} else if (randomFlavour < 7) {
    var randomFlavour = "bubblegum";
} else if (randomFlavour < 8) {
    var randomFlavour = "peanut butter";
} else if (randomFlavour < 9) {
    var randomFlavour = "mint";
} else {
    var randomFlavour = "gingerbread man";
}

console.log("Hello. I would like to have" + " " + randomFlavour + " " + "ice cream please.");
```

Comment: Put it in a function: `function foo() {...}`, then call the function when a button is clicked: `<button onclick="foo()">Run foo</button>`.

Comment: Instead of a giant if else block I recommend putting the values into an array and just index the flavors by the index: 'var randomFlavor = someArray[index];'

Comment: @TGH - the OP would also need to round the result, as Math.random() returns a float.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap your js code in a function. Set the onclick listener of the button to call your function.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                ... all of your javascript code ...
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">My Button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way might be to do something like this:

```
flavors = [
    'strawberry',
    'apple'];

function getRandomFlavor()
{
    random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * flavors.length);
    return flavors[random_index];
}

console.log(getRandomFlavor());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bm345/1/

Answer (score 0):

To execute a function when a button is clicked, you first need a button:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<button type="button">Click this button!</button>
```

Then you need to attach an event listener to the button. For beginners you will often be shown how to do this inline with an `[onclick]` attribute, but it's absolutely terrible practice and not a good habit to be in. If you were to add an event handler inline, you'd have to update all of them every time you wanted to do something as simple as change the event handler name. This is tedious and terrible for maintenance.

It's much easier long-term to bind events via JavaScript. You can do this a few different ways. The best is with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) (or a library that makes use of `addEventListener`, such as with [`jQuery.fn.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on)):

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
//this line of code tells the `buttonVariable` element to call the
//`callbackFunction` when the button is clicked
buttonVariable.addEventListener('click', callbackFunction, false);
```

Another way is to use the `onclick` property:

```
buttonVariable.onclick = callbackFunction;
```

For that code to work, you need to have selected the `<button>` element, and created a `callbackFunction` function:

```
//declare the variable
var buttonVariable;
//declare the function
function callbackFunction () {
    ...do stuff...
}
//select the button
buttonVariable = document.querySelector('button');
//bind the function to the button for click events
buttonVariable.addEventListener('click', callbackFunction, false);
```

It's also important to note that the script must execute *after* the `<button>` has been added to the DOM. JavaScript scripts are executed synchronously:

```
<script>
    var btn;
    //this returns null because the script executes before
    //the button element exists
    btn = document.querySelector('button');
</script>
<button type="button">Click this button!</button>
<script>
    var btn;
    //this returns an HTMLButtonElement object
    btn = document.querySelector('button');
</script>
```

[Here's a working example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VXE5j/)